# custom recovery behaviors

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want my robot to move back whenever it gets stuck, for this I want to write a custom recovery behavior. Can someone explain how to write a custom recovery behavior?

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249924/custom-recovery-behaviors/) by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 190 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just follow the same steps as creating a new layer in costmaps. Instead of sample_layers.h and sample_layers.cpp copy the code from rotate recovery because It adheres to the nav_core::RecoveryBehavior interface found in the nav_core package.

Now configure the Cmakelists.txt and package.xml file.

create a recovery_plugin.xml file and add it to the package.xml file under  tags.

---

Originally posted by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) with karma: 190 on 2016-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3